# How a anonymous user can view profile of authenticated user

Tags: 7, users, uri

How to see a profile of registered user by a anonymous user.

exampel : someuser2

when an administrator clicks any username or someuser2
it displays in this format in url on browser

http://mydomain/users/someuser1

When an anonymous user paste this link on browser,
the profile doesn't appear.

Is there any permissions to be ruled out ?, to display user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7

- /admin/people/permissions
- Users - Section --> View user profiles!

[Drupal 7 user Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPOjr.jpg)

In Drupal 6

- /admin/user/permissions
- user module --> access user profiles